# SeekBar listenner crashes app when in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a seekbar inside a fragment and when I run the app it crashes. The fragment is part of the main activity. Here is the code:

```
public class PalleteFragment extends Fragment {

  public TextView textView;
  private CanvasView canvas;

  public PalleteFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
  }


  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pallete, container, false);
  }

  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("Pen size: " + seekBar.getProgress());

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            canvas.setStrokeWidth(seekBar.getProgress());
            textView.setText("Pen size: " + seekBar.getProgress());
        }

        ...
    });
  }
}
```

Is something missing that I need to write?

Here is the error that occurs when the app crashes:
[image]

This is the CanvasView class in short:

```
public class CanvasView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {


private Paint mPaint;
private Path mPath;
private int mDrawColor;
private int mBackgroundColor;
private Canvas mExtraCanvas;
private Bitmap mExtraBitmap;
private int strokeWidth;

private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
private float mX, mY;

CanvasView(Context context) {

    super(context);
    setOnTouchListener(this);
    strokeWidth = 10;

    mBackgroundColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),
            R.color.simpleWhite, null);
    mDrawColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),
            R.color.simpleBlack, null);

    mPath = new Path();

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(mDrawColor);

    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    mPaint.setDither(true);

    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); // default: FILL
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND); // default: MITER
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND); // default: BUTT
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
}


public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet,GestureDetector mGestureDetector) {
    super(context);

    this.mGestureDetector = mGestureDetector;
    strokeWidth = 10;

    setOnTouchListener(this);
    mBackgroundColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),
            R.color.simpleWhite, null);
    mDrawColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),
            R.color.simpleBlack, null);

    mPath = new Path();

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(mDrawColor);

    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);

    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); // default: FILL
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND); // default: MITER
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND); // default: BUTT
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawBitmap(mExtraBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touchStart(x, y);
            updateColor(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()).getInt("color",getResources().getColor(R.color.simpleBlack)));
            setStrokeWidth(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()).getInt("stroke", 0));
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touchMove(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touchUp();
            break;
        default:
            // Do nothing.
    }
    return true;
}

private void touchStart(float x, float y) {
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        mExtraCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }
}

private void touchUp() {
    mPath.reset();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return false;
}

public void erase(){
    mExtraCanvas.drawColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),
            R.color.simpleWhite, null));
}

public void setStrokeWidth(int width) {
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(width);
}
```

}

The class is super long so I ommited other methods that weren't necessary for this question.

Here is the XML from the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Pen Size: " />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the app's directories:

[image]

Comment: Please add the crash log where the exception occurs.

Comment: canvas.setStrokeWidth(seekBar.getProgress()); I dont see you initializing the canvas in the fragment.

Comment: @AliEid the canvas is already initialized in another class i think

Comment: What is this canvas anyway? Even if you did initialize in another class, the current fragment doesnt know that. If this canvas view is not in the fragment_pallete layout, it will throw an NPE. Can you add it to the question?

Comment: Can you try removing canvas.setStrokeWidth(seekBar.getProgress()); and build the app and run it before proceeding?

Comment: @AliEid just edited the question for more information

Comment: If you are using CanvasView in the fragment you must initialize it: canvas = (CanvasView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_canvas_view);

Comment: @AliEid if I initialize the canvas the app crashes. Although if I remove canvas.setStrokeWidth(seekBar.getProgress()); the app doesn't crash but I need to send the seekBar.getProgress() value to the canvas

Comment: Look into the log error, locate the ones that say "Caused by" and post them in question. Also add your fragment's xml file and your full package name

Comment: Since this view is one you made using java, you have to declare it like this inside your xml: your.package.name.CanvasView

Comment: @AliEid I can't find the "caused by" log error, but I'll add the fragment's xml

Comment: Where is the canvas view in the xml? You have created a view using java, trying to pass data to it but you havent added it to the xml file. Your CanvasView is a View. It must be treated like any other view - like a TextView for example. You have to use it like this: your.package.name.views.CanvasView and add attributes to it just like the textview in your xml

Comment: @AliEid how do i create that? I'm new to android studio sorry

Comment: @AliEid just added!

Answer (score 0):

Use your CanvasView inside your fragment's xml file:

```
   <com.lionsilva.newpaint.customviews.CanvasView
        android:id="@+id/canvas_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then initialize it like any other view:

```
  private CanvasView canvas;
  canvas = view.findViewById(R.id.canvas_view);
  canvas.setStrokeWidth( seekBar.getProgress() );
```

Comment: The CanvasView is already open in the xml of the main activity. If I open it inside the fragment it creates a view I don't want

Comment: So you are passing data from this fragment to the mainactivity class?

Comment: In your codes, you had a NullPointerException because you were using a view that does not exist in your fragment. I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Please elaborate more in the question otherwise I cannot help anymore! Thank you!

Comment: no. the main activity has two fragments. one fragment has the seekbar, the other is a canvas. there is a class called CanvasView that draws on the canvas. I need to pass the value to that class

Comment: You should've already mentioned that. You need to make the CanvasView public inside your CanvasFragment. Then try in your PalleteFragment onViewCreated CanvasFragment cFragment = new CanvasFragment(); cFragment.canvas.setStrokeWidth...